# TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am new to transformers, so I tried to implement Bert class, where I receive this error message:
TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple

I googled it and it is said everywhere, the problem can be solved by adding the parameter 'return_dict=False'. I tried it this way:

```html
class BertFakesClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BertFakesClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased", return_dict=False)
        self.relu =  nn.ReLU()                    # relu activation function
        self.dense1_l = nn.Linear(768,512)        # dense layer 1
        self.output_l = nn.Linear(512,2)          # dense layer 2 (Output layer)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)       # softmax activation function

        
    
    def forward(self, tokens, attention_mask):
        outputs = self.bert(tokens, attention_mask)
        x = self.dense1_l(outputs)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.output_l(x)                           # output layer
        logits = self.softmax(x)                               
        return logits
```

I tried to add it to the forward method:

```html
class BertFakesClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BertFakesClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")
        self.relu =  nn.ReLU()                    # relu activation function
        self.dense1_l = nn.Linear(768,512)        # dense layer 1
        self.output_l = nn.Linear(512,2)          # dense layer 2 (Output layer)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)       # softmax activation function

        
    
    def forward(self, tokens, attention_mask):
        outputs = self.bert(tokens, attention_mask, return_dict=False)
        x = self.dense1_l(outputs)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.output_l(x)                           # output layer
        logits = self.softmax(x)                   
        
        return logits
```

I tried:

```html
def forward(self, tokens, attention_mask, return_dict):
        outputs = self.bert(tokens, attention_mask, return_dict=False)
```

I added return_dict=False at self.bert and forward method at the same time. I also tried to use instead:

```html
outputs = self.bert(tokens, attention_mask)
x = outputs['last_hidden_state'][:, 0, :]
```

But nothing is working. and I either get error message about input being a tuple or
TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not SequenceClassifierOutput
or another one
typeerror: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_dict'

I would really appreciate if anyone could help solving this issue.
Thanks in advance!